# "На кривій козі не під'їдеш" - це те саме, що й "об’їхати на кривій козі"?

Tags: синоніми, фразеологізми

Нещодавно довелося почути вислів "На кривій козі не під'їдеш", після чого виникло багато запитань, а саме - що означає цей вислів і до чого тут коза?
Пошуки в Інтернеті мене привели на цей форум, де я знайшов досить цікаву відповідь на друге запитання:

> Про криву козу вислів пішов з тих часів, коли мостів ще не було і
>   через яри і прірви перебиралися по перекинутому брёвну. Перебиралися
>   зазвичай на козі - це тварина відрізняється вестибулярним апаратом
>   високої точності і рівновагу тримає в будь-яких екстремальних
>   положеннях. Та й за роги зручно було триматися! Так ось кривих кіз для
>   таких переправ не використали - вони часто ступали повз колоди і
>   скидали їздця в яр або пропасти. Тому і говорили що на кривій козі НЕ
>   під'їдеш (на ту сторону).

Досить цікаве пояснення, однак не знаю чи воно вірне чи ні. Тут же дається пояснення цього вислову:

> Тобто такий хитрий, який не простодушний, не дуже довірлива людина, що
>   його ніяк, жодним чином не обдуриш, що не проведеш. Саме це і мається
>   на увазі в цій приказці про козу.

Однак, в іншій темі, на цьому ж форумі я знайшов вислів "об’їхати на кривій козі" і от, що там пишуть:

> фразеологізм "на кривій козі НЕ під'їдеш" іноді має і іншу редакцію -
>   "на кульгавий козі НЕ під'їдеш", Хоча сенс залишається одним і тим же.
>   Цей вислів вживають в тих випадках, коли говорять про людину, до якого
>   важко знайти підхід.
>
> походження фрази "на кривій козі НЕ під'їдеш" пов'язують з ярмарками,
>   на яких за старих часів скоморохи розважали купців і поміщиків. Справа
>   в тому, що блазні сідали на козу верхом і таким чином звеселяли
>   публіку. тільки надто серйозні і заможні особи не бачили таких
>   уявлень, оскільки артисти боялися до них навіть наблизитися.
>
> З тих пір виразом "на кривій козі НЕ під'їдеш" нагороджують занадто
>   зарозумілих, важливих і зарозумілих людей.

А ось [тут](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1000810/12/Lysenko_Vasiliy_-_Taemnicya_Zoryanoi_kimnati.html) цей вислів вжито так, що я взагалі не впевнений, що якесь пояснення із поданих вище можна використати (хіба люди, яких просто так не проведеш):

> — Бити фашистів, — розмірковував Гончар, — не так просто. Тут до них
>   **на кривій козі не під'їдеш**. У них танки, гармати, кулемети, автомати.
>   Воювати з ворогом треба з розумом, продумано.

А у цій [статті](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjln8jbzKzeAhWHDywKHeIiBsgQFjADegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua%2Fcgi-bin%2Firbis_nbuv%2Fcgiirbis_64.exe%3FC21COM%3D2%26I21DBN%3DUJRN%26P21DBN%3DUJRN%26IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD%3D1%26Image_file_name%3DPDF%2Fviche_2016_1-2_9.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Zpg1KqzSI4xQlEkciByJk) також пише, що це людина до якої складно знайти підхід.

Отож, що означає цей вислів - хитру людину, не довірливу, ту, до якої складно знайти підхід чи зарозумілу? Чи все одразу? І чи є різниця між "На кривій козі не під'їдеш" та "Об’їхати на кривій козі"?